# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "wx" when using pip & venv

Tags: python-3.x, pip, wxpython, python-venv

Not sure what is wrong with my `pip` and `venv`setup. But there must be an issue with the path, because I simply can't import any modules.

I've done the following (on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5):

```
>> brew update 
>> brew install python3
>> python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
>> cd projfolder
>> python3 -m venv env
>> source env/bin/activate
>> pip3 install wxPython
```

I can confirm that `wxPython` is present in my `venv` folder:
* wx
* wxPython-4.0.6.dist-info

My [source code](https://realpython.com/python-gui-with-wxpython/#installing-wxpython):

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title='Hello World')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Running this, I get:

```
>> py mathBlaster.py 
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>   File "mathBlaster.py", line 1, in <module>
>>     import wx
>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'
```

In fact every `import` results in the same `ModuleNotFoundError`

It seems that within the virtual env, it isn't aware of the installed modules:

```
>> pip3 show wxPython
```

... yields nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems your `py` runs a different Python, not the one from the virtualenv. Use `python` in virtualenvs.

Comment: I've added an alias "py" to resolve to python3.  So you think I should set the alias "python" to resolve to python3?

Comment: While a virtualenv is active you better use `python` and `pip`, or verify with `which` that `python3` and `pip3` are from the virtualenv.

Comment: Yes - once activated, I can confirm that `python3` and `pip` are from within the venv.    `pip show wxPython` also shows that `wxPython` exists within the venv. 

If I install `wxPython` globally it works.